# SQL query works in PHPMyAdmin but not in Java (JDBC)

Tags: java, jdbc, mariadb

I have generated the following string in java:

```
select * from `levelone_sessions` where user_session_key='-LIi-AlyYC37HfRezq7W' union select * from `changelang_sessions` where user_session_key='-LIi-AlyYC37HfRezq7W' union select * from `leveltwo_sessions` where user_session_key='-LIi-AlyYC37HfRezq7W' union select * from `levelthree_sessions` where user_session_key='-LIi-AlyYC37HfRezq7W' union select * from `sequence_sessions` where user_session_key='-LIi-AlyYC37HfRezq7W' union select * from `search_sessions` where user_session_key='-LIi-AlyYC37HfRezq7W' union select * from `settings_sessions` where user_session_key='-LIi-AlyYC37HfRezq7W'
```

and then converted it to a SQL statement using `PreparedStatement`. Now this SQL Query works perfectly fine in PHPMyAdmin and successfully gives the following output:

[PHPMyAdmin output screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLRfi.png)

But when the same query is being executed from within the java program, it throws the following exception:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'where user_session_key='-LIi-AlyYC37HfRezq7W'' at line 1
```

Not really sure why this is happening. Help!

**EDIT:**

Here is the java code that is actually generating the above string and executing it as a SQL statement.

```
Collection<String> activities = Utilities.AppActivities.values();
int no_of_activities = activities.size(), i=0;
query = "";
for(String activity: activities) {
if(i < no_of_activities-1) {
    query += "select * from `" + activity + "` where user_session_key='" + session_key + "' union ";
}
else {
    query += "select * from `" + activity + "` where user_session_key='" + session_key + "'";
}
i++;
}
System.out.println(query);
stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
rs = stmt.executeQuery();
duration = 0;
while(rs.next()) {
    duration += rs.getInt("duration");
}
```

Comment: Show us your Java code, formatted to be readable, and maybe someone will be able to help you.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen As suggested by you, I've added the java code in the edits :)

Comment: Are you aware that you are not really using the prepared statement?

Comment: Kind of aware that PreparedStatement generally uses '?' for parameters, but I don't really know if that'd help in the task I'm doing here. So I used this approach!

Comment: Your current code is vulnerable to SQL injection (which is likely also the cause of your error). Please use prepared statements properly. In any case, please post a [mcve], including sample values that trigger the error.